# align button to text input in foundation css

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

How do I get a button to line up with the text input using foundation css framework? I tried using the class "inline" which vertically aligns a label with a text input but it didn't work with the button. By default it seems the button's top edge is inline with the text input's top edge.

```
<form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="three columns">
            <input type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="two columns end">
        <button type="button" class="button inline">Do Something</button>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: use .two, .three{float:left } OR .columns{float:left}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `margin-top:-3px` to the button

Answer (score 1):

Well the Foundation way of doing that is simply to put the field and the button in the same row

```
   <div class="row">
```

and assign each field/button column as shown below

```
<div class="row">
  <%= form_tag search_path, method: 'get' do %>
    <div class="small-9 columns"> 
      <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], type: "search", class: "search-field" %>
    </div>
    <div class="small-3 columns"> 
      <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil, class: "search-form tiny button" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Well, something like that. Replace the logic with your forms.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting your divs to inline-block with vertical align?

```
div{display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;}
```

jsFiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/v4ALL/1

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the same problem, but this may help. I was stuck getting buttons in line with the text input fields with foundation 4 and found that the input[type="text"] width is set to 100% and set to display:block, so the input buttons don't have space to fit inline.

using the css hook

```
input[type="text"].yourClassName
```

If you override these properties

```
display:line;
width:80%;
```

then the button will be able to slot in on the right.

Hope that helps.